# How to convert __u32 to __be32 in Linux Kernel

Tags: c, linux-kernel, htonl

I've a variable

```
__be32 x;
```

I've a function

```
__u32 foo(void){
      __u32 a;
      return a;
}
```

I need to store the return of foo in variable `x`.

```
x=htonl(foo());
```

Is it correct?
I've a confusion that what are the return types of `ntohl()` and `htonl()`. Are they opposite of each other?

To check the output, I need to recompile the kernel and I don't want to trouble my system with any errors. So I'm asking here.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use the macros defined in kernel.h:

http://www.bruceblinn.com/linuxinfo/ByteOrder.html

> The following macros return the value after it has been converted.
>   Note: the linux/kernel.h header file is the header file that should be
>   included in the source files where these macros are used, but it is
>   not the header file where the macros are actually defined.

```
#include <linux/kernel.h>
__u16   le16_to_cpu(const __le16);
__u32   le32_to_cpu(const __le32);
__u64   le64_to_cpu(const __le64);

__le16  cpu_to_le16(const __u16);
__le32  cpu_to_le32(const __u32);
__le64  cpu_to_le64(const __u64);

__u16   be16_to_cpu(const __be16);
__u32   be32_to_cpu(const __be32);
__u64   be64_to_cpu(const __be64);

__be16  cpu_to_be16(const __u16);
__be32  cpu_to_be32(const __u32);
__be64  cpu_to_be64(const __u64);
```

Comment: ... and the macro to actually use here would be `x = cpu_to_be32(foo());`.

Comment: @unwind Thanks. But the aliases are easy to use.

Comment: @Nick Why so stubborn man. Why are you discarding my edit. I'm asking about `ntohl()` and `htonl()`. The link you provided mentioned them. I've got my answer and aliases are better than the actual macros. so I'm editing to include the aliases.

Comment: What's that? I was away... didn't discard anything. Put them back in and I'll approve... Or them as a different answer.

Comment: @Nick Don't know. At a moment I'm able to see my edit with "waiting for peer review". And the next moment, It's gone.

Comment: It got rejected by the review queue. Anyway - the htonl/ntohl macros are more specific to networking rather than general bit endianness. They're read as HostToNetworkLong and NetworkToHostLong.

Comment: Link is broken and I couldn't find a replacement ):

Comment: @Roi link still working for me. Maybe the site was down temporarily.

Comment: @Nick Oh! It really _is_ working now.