# What does cpu_to_le64 do?

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, linux-device-driver

What does `cpu_to_le64` function do? Where can I find the definition? The function gets an unsigned int as the input parameter. I have different variation in my device driver code, e.g. cpu_to_le32 or cpu_to_le16. Any idea what is this about?

Comment: translates value to little endian representation https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness . If your system uses  little endian order, than it does nothing, if big endian then it swaps the order of the bytes

Comment: @AlexHoppus That should be an answer.

Comment: It's a de facto duplicate to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21932790/how-to-convert-u32-to-be32-in-linux-kernel And the original link to nice article: http://bruceblinn.com/linuxinfo/ByteOrder.html

Answer (score 3):

It translates value to [little endian representation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness) . If your system uses little endian order, than it does nothing, if big endian then it swaps the order of the bytes